# Class in a <option> tag with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, select

Is it possible to add a class attribute in `<option>` tag using CodeIgniter?

```
<select name='state'>
    <option value="usa" class='top'>USA</option>
    <option value="ny">NY</option>       
</select>
```

If not, how to extend the Form helper to support this?

Comment: I generally write those myself, rather than relying on helpers to do the job for me. It's not something you need to use a helper.

Comment: But without the form helper, i have to do this way for each <option>: `<option value="one" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'one', ($model->selection == 'one')); ?> `. Now imagine 50 option tags. Cause of this Im searching a good solution or a improvement in FormHelper of CI.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can create your own helpers. See "Extending Helpers" here in the docs. I would do what is says and copy a "MY_helper.php" version to your application folder; don't mess with the core unless you really have to.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

You could use the values array and set a class and item in an array (and change the foreach near line 327 in the helper) or pass another array and check it in the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer not using helpers for such simple tasks... An inline if statement should be enough for your case.

If I'd want to dynamically populate an  tag I'd do something like this:

```
 <?php
   $result; //My result set
 ?>

<select>
 <?php foreach($result as $line): ?>
 <?php $class = ($condition===TRUE)?'this_class':''; ?>
      <option class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $line->data; ?></option>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

It might seem a little messy now, but for it feels better to write HTML when you need it instead of letting helpers do that.

If you use an IDE it even helps you use HTML highlighting which allows to better visualise your markup, without losing your php highlighting when you need :)

Comment: But I have a dropdown with 26 `<option>` tag (not dinamically), for each one I have to add this `<option value="one" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'one', ($model->selection == 'one')); ?>`, you still think that a Helper wouldn't be a good idea/solution? thank for your fast reply

Comment: This is my opinion, but I think it is best to keep php with php and HTML with HTML. So, since there is nothing dynamic in your <select> I see no reason of using a helper for that... Nothing to gain (you'll type the same amount of code, but in PHP) and you hide the markup from yourself... Not really practical if you ask me :/